# Key compination at pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keyevent

I'm using this python code https://gist.github.com/seankmartin/f660eff4787b586f94d5f678932bcd27#file-keyboardpress-py to get time for keyboard events. It's working well, but I need to get KEYDOWN and KEYUP also for capital letters and exclamation point. So I modified it by adding

```
elif event.key == key and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
    print (f"Pressed SHIFT + key {key_strs[i]} at time {ctr_adj_ms:.0f}ms")
```

to this part

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            for i, key in enumerate(keys):
                if event.key == key:
                    counters[i] = time.time()
                    ctr_adj = counters[i] - start_time
                    ctr_adj_ms = ctr_adj * 1000
                    time_log.append((key_strs[i], ctr_adj_ms))
                    print(f"Pressed key {key_strs[i]} at time {ctr_adj_ms:.0f}ms")
```

So now it looks like this

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            for i, key in enumerate(keys):
                if event.key == key:
                    counters[i] = time.time()
                    ctr_adj = counters[i] - start_time
                    ctr_adj_ms = ctr_adj * 1000
                    time_log.append((key_strs[i], ctr_adj_ms))
                    print(f"Pressed key {key_strs[i]} at time {ctr_adj_ms:.0f}ms")
                elif event.key == key and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                    counters[i] = time.time()
                    ctr_adj = counters[i] - start_time
                    ctr_adj_ms = ctr_adj * 1000
                    time_log.append((key_strs[i], ctr_adj_ms))
                    print (f"Pressed SHIFT + key {key_strs[i]} at time {ctr_adj_ms:.0f}ms")
```

But I still can't get no capitals letter, no exclamation point. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: IF the first if statement is true the `elif` clause will never run. Try reversing the two code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard events `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) create a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object with additional attributes. The key that was pressed can be obtained from the `key` attribute (e.g. `K_RETURN` , `K_a`) and the `mod` attribute contains a bitset with additional modifiers (e.g. `KMOD_LSHIFT`). The `unicode` attribute provides the Unicode representation of the keyboard input. e.g.:

```py
for event in pygme.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            if event.mod in [pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT, pygame.KMOD_RSHIFT]:

                # capital 'A'
                # ...
```

Comment: thanks, I managed to get capital letters, but still can't get any punctuation mark (exclamation point and others), I know I should do this with event.unicode , but don't know exactly how

Comment: When `event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN` you can get the value of `event.unicode` like `text = event.unicode`.